# how to secure phpmyadmin access through .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Usually, we are getting access to phpmyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin
and we are pass user name and password.

```
 1.localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

for cloud:
     2.125.125.14.12/phpmyadmin

so its easy to hacker to crack it. 
How we can secure phpmyadmin by using .htaccess file?

**Note: its for ubuntu**

Comment: The statement "protect phpmyadmin by using .htaccess" is too broad. You need to specify a desired behaviour.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am assuming that you have installed mysql.

1. Install *phpmyadmin*:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
   ```
2. Copy:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
   ```
3. Edit:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
   ```

   enter following line just after "`DirectoryIndex index.php`":

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```
4. Edit *.htaccess*

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
   ```

   Enter following content:

   ```
   AuthType Basic
   Authname "Restricted files"
   AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   ```
5. `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`
6. `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd username`
7. Enter new password
8. Restart *apache*

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use the order way, ie:

```
<Directory "/path/to/phpmyadmin">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Comment: which file?  nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo htpasswd -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd username`